# Как исправить ошибку: "Unhandled Promise Rejection: [object Object]" библиотека react-yandex-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Такая проблема, что для отрисовки карты я использую react-yandex-maps, все работает нормально когда запускаю фронт по локальной сети, но если я запускаю уже не по локалке, появляется ошибка:
**[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: [object Object]**

Вот компонента Map:

```
import React from 'react'
import { YMaps, Map, Placemark, ZoomControl } from '@pbe/react-yandex-maps';
import { placemarks } from '../../../data/data';

import { defaultState } from '../../../data/data';


export const MapForm = (props) => {

    const onClickSubmit = (nameAdmin) => {
        props.setValue((value) => ({
            ...value,
            [props.typeObject]: nameAdmin
        }))

        props.setActive(false)
    }

    return (
        <YMaps>
            <Map defaultState={defaultState}>
                {placemarks.map(el => (
                    <Placemark geometry={el.coor} onClick={
                        () => onClickSubmit(el.name)
                    } options={{
                        iconColor: "#CC2222",
                        hasHint: true,
                        openHintOnHover: true,
                    }} properties={
                        {
                            iconCaption: el.name,
                        }
                    } />
                ))}
                <ZoomControl options={{ float: "right" }} />
            </Map>
        </YMaps>
    )

}
```

Я пытался найти решение проблемы в документации библиотеки, ничего не смог к сожалению найти, есть ли какие-нибудь варианты решений?

Comment: А где запускаете? Как запускаете?

Comment: Покажите стек трейс ошибки. Сама ошибка говорит о том, что вы не обрабатываете exception от промиса. т.е. где то есть then() но нет catch() который должен ловить ошибку